# How to link a css file in python

Tags: python, css, django

I'm sending a message with HTML via Python. Now, I'd like to style it, I've tried to write the style code into the html but there are problems because curling braces {}. Can I link the css file in Python?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
         <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/message_style.css"> #I've a static folder
     </head>
     <body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both inline stylings and also insert your CSS files into your HTML from a static folder like this:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %} or {% load static %}
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/message_style.css' %}">
```

**Note:** You should load static directory before using `{% static 'relative address to the file' %}`, and both `{% load static from staticfiles %}` or `{% load static %}` will do the same for you but the first one is more explicit.

**EDIT:** If you want to send out emails and make an email template you should use inline styles and use tables, to achieve that you can check [this link](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770) for more information.

Comment: I'm sending this via email from a sever. When I use {% static ' ... ' %} it throw me the error: '''invalid syntax (<fstring>, line 1'''

Comment: @VicenteC Usually in emails we use inline styles, I will share some useful sources with you in the edited post.

Comment: You have to call `{% load static %}` *before* calling the style sheet.